# Whats widgets should be used for creating one TextField between two toggle buttons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to do the following:

[image]

By other words only one of two buttons can be selected and there must be a `TextField` between them. The only solution I found is to use two `ToggleButtons` with TextField between them. I mean:

```
Row(
 children: [
   ToggleButtons(...),
   TextField(...),
   ToggleButtons(...),
 ]
)
```

But I don't like this solution because two buttons must belong to one  widget. As the same time time when I insert TextField in ToggleButton.children TextField becomes third button and this is not what I need.

Could anyone say how to solve such a problem in Flutter?

Comment: *TextField becomes third button* Do you mean, you like to ignore inputting text by user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom widget to handle this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: CustomCounter())));
  }
}

class CustomCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomCounter({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomCounter> createState() => _CustomCounterState();
}

class _CustomCounterState extends State<CustomCounter> {
  bool minusSelected = false;
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            minusSelected = true;
            setState(() {
              int currentValue = int.tryParse(_textEditingController.text) ?? 0;
              _textEditingController.text = (currentValue -= 1).toString();
              _textEditingController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                  TextPosition(offset: _textEditingController.text.length));
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: minusSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(4)),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1)),
            child: Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textEditingController,
              inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
              ),
            )),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            minusSelected = false;
            setState(() {
              int currentValue = int.tryParse(_textEditingController.text) ?? 0;
              _textEditingController.text = (currentValue += 1).toString();
              _textEditingController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                  TextPosition(offset: _textEditingController.text.length));
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: minusSelected == false ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(4),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(4)),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1)),
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: Could you take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73152900/how-to-scroll-dialog-content-to-focused-textfield-in-flutter ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use TextField, you can use a simple container to set your value

```
Row(
 children: [
   ToggleButtons(...),
   Container(child: Text(yourValue),
   ToggleButtons(...),
 ]
)
```

Or you can use readonly Textfield,

TextField(readonly: true,...)